# Maintaining UserTransactions across session

Tags: session, servlets, jakarta-ee, websphere, jta

Working in a servlet, Websphere Application Server allows you to store UserTransaction objects in the HttpSession and retrieve it later, previously with a wrapper class, but now automatically:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fpublic_html%2Fapi%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fservlet%2Fsession%2FUserTransactionWrapper.html

Yet when I begin a transaction, then retrieve it later and attempt to commit, I recieve the error that no transaction exists to commit.  I assume the servlet is closing the transaction automatically when the http request finishes on each servlet call - what, then, is the purpose of being able to mantain this userTransaction across sessions?

Is there any way to achieve what I want (I'm using Java with WAS)?